# asynchronous programming in dart (Futures, await)

Tags: asynchronous, dart

what changes should I do to the following code to get the following output:

```
Task 1 complete
Task 4 complete
Task 2 complete
Task 3 complete with task 2 data
```

I currently getting the outputs given below:

Task 1 complete

Task 2 complete

Task 3 complete with task 2 data

Task 4 complete

```
import 'dart:async';
    
    void main() {
      performTasks();
    }

void performTasks() async {
  task1();
  String task2Result = await task2();
  task3(task2Result);
  task4();
}

void task1() {
  String result = 'task 1 data';
  print('Task 1 complete');
}

Future<String> task2() async {
  Duration threeSeconds = Duration(seconds: 3);
  String result;

  await Future.delayed(threeSeconds, () {
    result = 'task 2 data';
    print('Task 2 complete');
  });

  return result;
}

void task3(String task2Data) {
  String result = 'task 3 data';
  print('Task 3 complete with $task2Data');
}

void task4() {
  String result = 'task 4 data';
  print('Task 4 complete');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `task4` after waiting for `task2`.
So:

```dart
void performTasks() async {
  task1();
  task4();
  String task2Result = await task2();
  task3(task2Result);
}
```

That looks pretty obvious, so I'm assuming your real problem is more complicated, and you can't move `test4()` around like that.

In that case, you should not use `await`. The `await` ensures that everything written after the `await` also executes after the awaited future has completed.

Instead you can fall back on the `Future` API:

```dart
void performTasks() { // no `async`
  task1();
  task2().then(task3); // no `await`
  task4();
}
```

This sets up `task2()` to run, and when that is done, it calls `task3` with the result. It doesn't *wait* for anything, though, and it executes `task4` immediately after setting this up.

The [`then` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/then.html) on futures takes a callback, and eventually calls that with the result of the future. Here `task3` takes one argument, so it can directly be used as that callback.

That assumes that `task2`'s result is directly usable as an argument to `task3`. If not, and you have to capture the result and manipulate it first, you'd do it as:

```dart
void performTasks() { // no `async`
  task1();
  task2().then((result2) { // still no await here!
    var argument3 = manipulate(result2);
    // ... and whatever else you want to do 
    // between task2 completing and task3 starting.
    task3(argument3);
  });
  task4();
}
```

Comment: I want to further clarify the change. How does the 'result' variable from task2() get passed to task3() in  your code (task2().then(task3);)

Comment: Further, lets say that I return two variables of two different data types (result1 and result2) from task2() but only pass result1 to task3(). How do I execute this?

Comment: Here `task2` returns a `Future<String>`, so it only returns one string. The `result` variable is just a local variable inside `task2`, the only thing it can *return* is what the future is completed with. I've added an example of what you can do if that is not exactly the argument you need to pass to `task3`.

Answer (score 1):

in `performTasks()`, you should move `task4();` right after `task1();`.